# Importing a JS npm library in Svelte

Tags: javascript, npm, svelte

I don't understand how to import a random npm library in Svelte.

Take the [scrapegoat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrapegoat) library for example, a library to read CalDAV objects. I created a brand new Svelte project:

```sh
$ npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project
$ cd my-svelte-project/
$ npm install
$ npm install -D scrapegoat
```

Not sure if it should be added to the devDependencies but it doesn't seem to make a lot of difference if it is not. Now, in the `src/App.svelte` I add this singe line in the existing `<script>` tag.

```js
import scrapegoat from 'scrapegoat'
```

Running `npm run dev` throws the following error:

```sh
[!] Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
node_modules/scrapegoat/package.json (2:9)
1: {
2:   "_from": "scrapegoat@^2.0.0",
            ^
3:   "_id": "scrapegoat@2.0.0",
4:   "_inBundle": false,
Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need @rollup/plugin-json to import JSON files)
    at error (node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:158:30)
    at Module.error (node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12420:16)
    at Module.tryParse (node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12823:25)
    at Module.setSource (node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:12726:24)
    at ModuleLoader.addModuleSource (node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:22197:20)
```

This is what I understood from [Rich Harris'](https://dev.to/richharris/comment/f8j9) reply but I am clearly missing something.

Comment: the package.json of scrapegoat should not be like the one in the error, it should be like this : https://github.com/peerigon/scrapegoat/blob/master/package.json

Comment: @JeffProd Thanks. I used `yarn add` instead of `npm install` which does not add that extra matadata but I get the same error, this time on the `"name": "scrapegoat"` line, the semicolon is an "unexpected token".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you’re importing imports its own package.json. Rollup won’t handle JSON imports by default, so you will need to install the [json plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-json) and add it to your Rollup config.

Comment: I added the plugin but forgot to add it to the configuration. The error is now gone. Thanks! I get a different error now, in the browser: "fs is not defined". I suppose that's node's `fs` not being available in the browser.

Comment: Correct, if it's accessing the filesystem you won't be able to use it inside a Svelte component, which only runs client-side.